# Trouble with vgamepad library in Python: Pressing Buttons

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Python script using the `vgamepad` library to simulate button presses on a virtual `gamepad`. According to the documentation, I should use `gamepad.press_button(vg.XUSB_BUTTON.XUSB_GAMEPAD_A)` to press a specific button.

However, when I tried using an integer directly, like `gamepad.press_button(0)`, I didn't get any errors, but the button press didn't seem to have any effect.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
from vgamepad import *

# Initialize the virtual gamepad
gamepad = vgamepad.VDS4Gamepad()

# Attempt to press button 0 using an integer
gamepad.press_button(0)
```

I expected this to simulate a button press, but nothing happened. Am I missing something? Is there a specific reason why using an integer directly didn't produce an error but also didn't result in the expected behavior?

Comment: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/dualshock-4-ps4-controller-keycode-values.81030/

Answer (score 0):

According to their [documentation](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad#:%7E:text=All%20available%20buttons%20are%20defined%20in%20XUSB_BUTTON%3A) only the specified constants should be used for the press_button() function. I don't think it is intended for use with integers. [Here](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad/blob/main/vgamepad/win/vigem_commons.py) is the link for the file containing the constants.

Why not throw errors? I'm not sure, but I can tell you it's not intended to use outside of the defined values.