# using `vgamepad` only works on L2 for driving a car in fortnite

Tags: python

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to implement DS4 controller input using the vgamepad library in Python for Fortnite. I've followed the steps outlined in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738675/trouble-with-vgamepad-library-in-python-pressing-buttons) and ensured that all controls work fine, except for driving a car. Only the L2 button seems to be working in this scenario.

Edit:

i don't know about other games

Edit2:

the car moves with all controls when match started but it's not working after i press l2 (and then only l2 works)

Edit3:

Here is my code:

```
from pygame import init,joystick as j
from pygame.event import get
from vgamepad import VDS4Gamepad,VX360Gamepad
from time import sleep,time
init()
j.init()
gamepad = VDS4Gamepad()
joystick = None
condition = True
platform = 'ps4'
incluer2 = False
incluel2 = False
incluer = True
incluel = True
r2round = 3
l2round = 3
rround = 2
lround = 2
st = .01
wt = 1.044
def ps4():
    global joystick
    while condition:
        while j.get_count() == 0:
            sleep(1)
        if joystick is not None and not joystick.get_init():
            joystick = None
        if joystick == None:
            joystick = j.Joystick(0)
            joystick.init()
        get()
        if joystick.get_axis(4) > -0.5:
            gamepad.press_button(1024)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(1024)
        if joystick.get_axis(5) > -0.5:
            gamepad.press_button(2048)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(2048)
        if joystick.get_button(0):
            gamepad.press_button(32)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(32)
        if joystick.get_button(1):
            gamepad.press_button(64)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(64)
        if joystick.get_button(2):
            gamepad.press_button(16)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(16)
        if joystick.get_button(3):
            gamepad.press_button(128)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(128)
        if joystick.get_button(4):
            gamepad.press_button(4096)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(4096)
        if joystick.get_button(5):
            gamepad.press_special_button(1)
        else:
            gamepad.release_special_button(1)
        if joystick.get_button(6):
            gamepad.press_button(8192)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(8192)
        if joystick.get_button(7):
            gamepad.press_button(16384)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(16384)
        if joystick.get_button(8):
            gamepad.press_button(32768)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(32768)
        if joystick.get_button(9):
            gamepad.press_button(256)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(256)
        if joystick.get_button(10):
            gamepad.press_button(512)
        else:
            gamepad.release_button(512)
        if joystick.get_button(11):
            gamepad.directional_pad(0)
        elif joystick.get_button(12):
            gamepad.directional_pad(4)
        elif joystick.get_button(13):
            gamepad.directional_pad(6)
        elif joystick.get_button(14):
            gamepad.directional_pad(2)
        else:
            gamepad.directional_pad(10)
        if joystick.get_button(15):
            gamepad.press_special_button(2)
        else:
            gamepad.release_special_button(2)
        gamepad.left_joystick_float(x_value_float=joystick.get_axis(0), y_value_float=joystick.get_axis(1))
        gamepad.right_joystick_float(x_value_float=joystick.get_axis(2), y_value_float=joystick.get_axis(3))
        gamepad.left_trigger_float(joystick.get_axis(4))
        gamepad.right_trigger_float(joystick.get_axis(5))
        gamepad.update()
        sleep(st)
ps4()
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Sure, Question edited.

Comment: L2 was the left trigger, which you use to aim or brake (when driving), right? Do you control it in this line?: `gamepad.left_trigger_float(joystick.get_axis(4))`

Comment: Yes that's what i did in the code.

Comment: Yes that's what i did in the code. Edit: No actually when i read your comment again i have to tell you that i use `gamepad.press_button(1024)` for aim.