# Difficulty Simulating DS4 Controller Input for Forward Movement in Fortnite Cars

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python script to simulate DS4 controller input for driving vehicles in Fortnite. Strangely, I can only drive cars in reverse; forward movement doesn't seem to work. Surprisingly, motorcycles and cars in Rocket Racing work as expected.

I suspect that Fortnite might be using a different button or input mapping for driving cars forward. I've included the relevant parts of my code below. Could someone help me identify any potential issues or suggest modifications to make forward movement work for Fortnite cars?

My code is based on this question:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760861/using-vgamepad-only-works-on-l2-for-driving-a-car-in-fortnite)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there a problem with my question?

Comment: How does your code differ from the code in the question you linked?

Comment: @iolim5678 I got the code from that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dead-zone to the L2 button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While it didn't solve the problem i awarded the bounty to avoid wasting it. Happy coding!